# Currency Discord.py Bot Problem with files

Tags: python, file, discord, file-writing

So here is my code:

```
@client.command()
async def beg(message):
    x = message.author.id
    idk = str(x) + ".wallet"
    file = open(idk, "w")
    file.close()
    file = open(idk, "r")
    first = file.read(1)
    if not first:
        file.close()
        file = open(idk, "w")
        file.write(str(0))
    file.close()
    file = open(idk, "r")
    money1 = file.readline()
    money1 = int(money1)
    a = random.randint(1, 750)
    money1 = money1 + a
    print(money1)
    money1 = str(money1)
    print(money1)
    file.close()
    file = open(idk, "w")
    print(money1)
    file.write(money1)
    print(money1)
    file.close()
    await message.channel.send(f"You got {a} dollars from begging congrats")


@client.command()
async def bal(message):
    x = message.author.id
    idk = str(x) + ".wallet"
    file = open(idk, "r")
    moni = file.readline()
    await message.channel.send(f'You have {moni} in your wallet right now.')
```

Please assume that I have all the necessary imports.
I figured that the problem was these few lines:

```
if not first:
    file.close()
    file = open(idk, "w")
    file.write(str(0))
```

Where even if the file isn't empty it still rewrites over the file and writes 0. I don't know how to fix this though. Thank you in advance! All help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the file open mode `w` opens the file and rewrites the whole thing. If you want to add a string, you have to open it with the append mode.

```py
with open('file.txt', 'a') as f:
    f.write('something')
```

this will add `something` to the file.

If you want to modify the file

```py
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    file_str = f.readlines()
modify(file_str)
with open('file.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(file_str)
```

Comment: Yes I know that 'W' rewrites the whole thing, the problem is that I'm only trying to add a 0 into the file if the file is empty. I do this to solve the errors later with readline having something about nothing to read.

Comment: yeah use mode `a` then.

Comment: No but...... Like the problem is if i used a then it will add 0 to my current balance, multiplying it by 10 every time I used the command. The problem is with detecting if the file is empty or not.

Comment: Alright I rewrote my code and used a json file, i don't need help anymore, but others might!